# How to test that asyncio.Queue did NOT get something pushed

Tags: message-queue, pytest, python-asyncio, pytest-asyncio

I'm currently writing some async tests with pytest and found myself running into the following situation.

Consider we have an `asyncio.Queue` called `peer2_subscriber` that we want to check if it received a certain message (after triggering some action, omitted for brevity)

```
peer, cmd, msg = await asyncio.wait_for(
    peer2_subscriber.get(),
    timeout=1,
)

assert peer == peer2
assert isinstance(cmd, Transactions)
assert msg[0].hash == txs[0].hash
```

Now, consider that I want to test that another `asyncio.Queue` did NOT something pushed.

I found myself creating such a helper method.

```
async def wait_with_fallback(fn, fallback):
    try:
        return await asyncio.wait_for(
            fn(),
            timeout=1
        )
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return fallback
```

And then in the test I write something like:

```
val = await wait_with_fallback(
    peer1_subscriber.get,
    None
)

assert val == None
```

I wonder if there's an existing pattern that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern works, so I would say it's "correct", for certain values of correct… It's mostly stylistic views here. I would write either

```
await asyncio.sleep(1)
assert peer1_subscriber.empty()
```

or

```
await asyncio.sleep(1)
val = peer1_subscriber.get_nowait()
assert val is None
```